# Width of select2 input is getting smaller when bootstrap panel is open by default

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

Inside a bootstrap `panel` I have a `form` where I use `select2` for select inputs.

The problem is that when I define the `panel` to be closed by default (by removing the `in` from the `class="panel-collapse collapse"` ) the width of the `select2` input is getting smaller!

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  placeholder: "Select...",
  allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> closed by default
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="form" method="post" action="rpt-action?do=rpt-request-change-mould-submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <select name="action" class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="toPrepare">Prepare</option>
                        <option value="toProduction">Produce</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" rows="3" /></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> open by default
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="form" method="post" action="rpt-action?do=rpt-request-change-mould-submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <select name="action" class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="toPrepare">Prepare</option>
                        <option value="toProduction">Produce</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" rows="3" /></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, if I add the `in` to the class then the width of  the `select2` input follows its parent's column with!

I don't understand why this is happening...  Any ideas how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily solve this using the [width option](https://select2.org/appearance#container-width) of the plugin, in this particular case using `width: "100%"` will fix it, like this:

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    placeholder: "Select...",
    allowClear: true,
    width: "100%"
});
```

Check the working example:

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  placeholder: "Select...",
  allowClear: true,
  width: "100%"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> closed by default
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="form" method="post" action="rpt-action?do=rpt-request-change-mould-submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <select name="action" class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="toPrepare">Prepare</option>
                        <option value="toProduction">Produce</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" rows="3" /></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus mright-1"></i> open by default
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <form id="form" method="post" action="rpt-action?do=rpt-request-change-mould-submit" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <fieldset>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <select name="action" class="js-example-basic-single js-states form-control" required>
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="toPrepare">Prepare</option>
                        <option value="toProduction">Produce</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-xs-2 control-label">Notes</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" rows="3" /></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.select2-container {
   width: 100% !important
}
```

**This CSS lines will resolve this Issue**